# Analyse clustered items from different scales?

Tags: regression, factor-analysis, covariance-matrix

I am a non stat person so pls be kind in your reply! What sort of statistic can I use to compare how the items of 3 different Likert scales covariate? My respondents sample is 150 ppl. Each respondent completes all 3 scales. I would like to understand if there is a pattern between the way items of different scales are rated, across these 150 ppl. So, basically, if there is a trend, or average pattern in the way how this sample rates these 3 sets of scales. What is it, is it factor analysis, regression, or else. Don't have a clue. Any advice is welcome!
Thank you.
Amy